# Django sessions doesn't allow me to add items in my cart

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-sessions

I am creating an eCommerce store and I use Django sessions to store the cart information. However, for some reason, only 2 items get stored in the cart and no more. Once I add the first item, it stays there as it is. Then I add the 2nd item. However, when I add the 3rd item, the 2nd item is overwritten by the 3rd one, still keeping only 2 products in the cart.

I feel it would be a simple logic error but I can't seem to figure it out.

My views.py...

```
def shop(request):

    if not request.session.get('order1'):
        request.session['order1'] = []


    if request.method == "POST":
        quantity = int(request.POST.get('quantity'))
        name = request.POST.get('name')

        if quantity >= 1:
            request.session.get('order1').append({"quantity":quantity, "name":name})
            
            context = {
                "check":request.session.get('order1'),
            }
        else:
            messages.warning(request, "You have entered an invalid quantity")
            context={}
    
    else:
        context={}
    return render(request, "store/shop.html", context)
```

And the output of the `context = {"check":request.session.get('order1')}` is something like this `[{'quantity': 1, 'name': 'Tissot Watch for men - black star striped'}, {'quantity': 2, 'name': 'Jewelry Bangles Stripes for Girls'}]` and always stays with only 2 items.

Is there any error in the code that I have done?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `request.session['order1']` is a list any changes to it will not be detected as "changes" by the session middleware since it is still the same object.

One solution is to set the `modified` attribute on the session

```
# In your view after appending to a list in the session
request.session.modified = True
```

Another solution to this is to update your settings to [save the session on every request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#session-save-every-request) regardless of if the middleware thinks it's been changed or not

```
# In settings.py
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
```